# CREATE DATABASE on RAW partitions no longer works?

Tags: sql-server, storage

I'm attempting to create a database using two raw, i.e. unformatted, partitions.

Microsoft Docs states you can do this, you simply need to specify only the drive letter of the raw partition, as in:

```
CREATE DATABASE DirectDevice 
ON (NAME = DirectDevice_system, FILENAME = 'S:')
LOG ON (NAME = DirectDevice_log, FILENAME = 'T:')
```

However, SQL Server 2017 returns this error:

> Msg 5170, Level 16, State 4, Line 1
>   Cannot create file 'S:' because it already exists. Change the file path or the file name, and retry the operation.
>   Msg 1802, Level 16, State 4, Line 1
>   CREATE DATABASE failed. Some file names listed could not be created. Check related errors.

The pertinent bit of the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-database-sql-server-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#arguments) states:

> If the file is on a raw partition, os_file_name must specify only the drive letter of an existing raw partition. Only one data file can be created on each raw partition.

And yes, drive S: and T: are both unformatted raw partitions that do exist in my system:

```
DISKPART> detail partition

Partition 4
Type    : ebd0a0a2-b9e5-4433-87c0-68b6b72699c7
Hidden  : No
Required: No
Attrib  : 0000000000000000
Offset in Bytes: 999934656512

  Volume ###  Ltr  Label        Fs     Type        Size     Status     Info
  ----------  ---  -----------  -----  ----------  -------  ---------  --------
* Volume 6     T                RAW    Partition    127 MB  Healthy

DISKPART> select partition 3

Partition 3 is now the selected partition.

DISKPART> detail partition

Partition 3
Type    : ebd0a0a2-b9e5-4433-87c0-68b6b72699c7
Hidden  : No
Required: No
Attrib  : 0000000000000000
Offset in Bytes: 1000067825664

  Volume ###  Ltr  Label        Fs     Type        Size     Status     Info
  ----------  ---  -----------  -----  ----------  -------  ---------  --------
* Volume 7     S                RAW    Partition    129 MB  Healthy
```

Removing the colon from the drive letters, as in `FILENAME = 'S'` and `FILENAME = 'T'`, results in:

> Msg 5105, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
>   A file activation error occurred. The physical file name 'S' may be incorrect. Diagnose and correct additional errors, and retry the operation.
>   Msg 1802, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   CREATE DATABASE failed. Some file names listed could not be created. Check related errors.

[SQL Server 2000 Documentation](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=51958) shows the following example under the `CREATE DATABASE` section:

> H. Use raw partitions
>   This example creates a database called Employees using raw partitions. The raw partitions must exist when the statement is executed, and only one file can go on each raw partition.

```
    USE master
    GO
    CREATE DATABASE Employees
    ON
    ( NAME = Empl_dat,
        FILENAME = 'f:',
        SIZE = 10,
        MAXSIZE = 50,
        FILEGROWTH = 5 )
    LOG ON
    ( NAME = 'Sales_log',
        FILENAME = 'g:',
        SIZE = 5MB,
        MAXSIZE = 25MB,
        FILEGROWTH = 5MB )
    GO
```

However, the above example shows `SIZE`, `MAXSIZE`, and `FILEGROWTH` parameters which are clearly not required for SQL Server Data Files stored on RAW partitions.

Further details from the SQL Server 2000 documentation, specifically concerning raw drives:

> **Using Raw Partitions**
>   Microsoft® SQL Server™ 2000 supports the use of raw partitions for creating database files. Raw partitions are disk partitions that have not been formatted with a Microsoft Windows NT® file system, such as FAT and NTFS. In some cases, using databases created on raw partitions can yield a slight performance gain over NTFS or FAT. However, for most installations the preferred method is to use files created on NTFS or FAT partitions.
>   When creating a database file on a raw partition, you do not specify the physical names of the files comprising the database; you specify only the drive letters of the disks on which the database files should be created.
>   If you are using Microsoft Windows® 2000 Server, you can create mounted drives to point to raw partitions. When you mount a local drive at an empty folder, Windows 2000 assigns a drive path to the drive rather than a drive letter. Mounted drives are not subject to the 26-drive limit imposed by drive letters; therefore, you can use an unlimited number of raw partitions. When you create a database file on a mounted drive, you must end the drive path to the file name with a trailing backslash (), for example, E:\Sample name. For information about creating a mounted drive, see the Windows 2000 Server documentation.
>
> There are several limitations to consider when using raw partitions:
>   Only one database file can be created on each raw partition. The logical partition must be configured as a single database file, because there is no file system on the raw partition.
>
> Standard file-system operations such as copy, move, and delete cannot be used with raw partitions.
>
> Database files located on raw partitions cannot be backed up using the Windows NT Backup utility. However, SQL Server database or transaction log backups can still be created.
>
> Database files on raw partitions cannot be automatically expanded. Either initially create the database at its full size, or manually expand the database files. For more information, see Expanding a Database.
>
> Only lettered partitions, such as E:, or mounted drives, such as E:\Sample name\ can be used. Numbered devices cannot be used.
>
> File-system services such as bad block replacement are not available with raw partitions.

---

<sup>This was inspired by [Brent Ozar's post about SQL Server 6.5](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2018/05/book-review-inside-sql-server-6-5/), which *did* support raw partitions</sup>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can confirm raw partitions work, as expected, with SQL Server 2000 SP4 on Windows XP x64.

I just ran the following through Query Analyzer (shudders) against SQL Server 2000 SP4:

```
CREATE DATABASE t
ON PRIMARY 
(
    NAME = t_primary
    , FILENAME = 'E:'
)
LOG ON 
(
    NAME = t_log
    , FILENAME = 'F:'
);
```

The results:

> The CREATE DATABASE process is allocating 0.64 MB on disk 't_primary'.
>   The CREATE DATABASE process is allocating 1.00 MB on disk 't_log'.

The above `CREATE DATABASE t` code works with SQL Server 2005 on Windows XP x64; the only output is `Command(s) completed successfully.`

SSMS shows the following when you look at the database files:

[image]

Isn't that about as cool as a bucket of bolts?

SQL Server 2012 SP1 on Windows Server 2012 Standard, with SQL Server Management Studio service account set to "Local System":

[image]

SQL Server 2014 (12.0.5000.0) running as "Local System" on Windows Server 2012 exhibits the same behavior as SQL Server 2017; i.e., it returns this error message:

> Msg 5170, Level 16, State 4, Line 1
>   Cannot create file 'E:' because it already exists. Change the file path or the file name, and retry the operation.
>   Msg 1802, Level 16, State 4, Line 1
>   CREATE DATABASE failed. Some file names listed could not be created. Check related errors.

Comment: does it means that Raw Partition is not any longer supported on newer versions?

Comment: I haven't tried it on SQL Server 2019 or 2022, but I'd assume it doesn't work.  Raw partitions are so last century.